# PHP export a specific SVN revision?

Tags: php, svn, svn-export

Is there a way of exporting a specific revision from SVN via PHP? The [`svn_function()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-export.php) does currently not offer such a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the PHP mailing list:

> As of version 1.0.0 of the SVN PECL
>   extension, you can provide a 4th
>   parameter (undocumented) to
>   svn_export() to specify a revision
>   number.

Changelog of 1.0.0: http://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=svn&version=1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it.

I assume you have to `svn_checkout()` first (that one accepts a revision number) and then export from there.